# What's the word for a place of ambush?

Tags: single-word-requests

I mean you're planning to ambush someone and so you look for the best place to do that. What would that place be?
E.g The enemy is coming this way, let's find a ____ quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, ambushes are not set up quickly. They are planned in advance to maximize terrain advantages, use the cover of night, etc. This tends to involve lying in wait for a long period of time. This position in which they are hidden is called **an ambush**

[(MW.com)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambush#h2)

> 2: the concealed position from which a surprise attack is made.
> *a group of soldiers lying in ambush*

If you are simply looking for a place of concealment for a rapidly thrown together surprise attack, the term is **hiding place.**

[(MW.com)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hiding%20place)

> a place where someone or something is hidden or can be hidden. *My
> favorite hiding place when I was a kid was in the attic*.